# Após consulta php abrir resultado em uma nova página

Tags: php, jquery

Como posso, se tem como, abrir uma nova página após retorno de uma consulta no `php`, o que tenho hoje é isso aqui:

```
$(function () {
$("#frmConsulta").validate({
    submitHandler: function (form) {

        var data = $(form).serialize();
        console.log(data);  

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'ajax/pRelatorioEvolucaoSafra.php',
            data: data,
            dataType: 'html',

            success: function (response) {

                // EXIBINDO O RETORNO DAS INFORMAÇÕES   
                $("#msgRelatorio").html(response);

                $('#frmConsulta').each(function () {
                    this.reset();
                });
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                console.log(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError);
                $("#msgRelatorio").html('<div class="alert alert-danger fade in"><button class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button><i class="fa-fw fa fa-times"></i><strong>ATENÇÃO!</strong> Ocorreu um erro ao tentar efetuar a consulta. Contate o suporte técnico.</div>');
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
});
```

});

No retorno estou posicionado uma tabela na div `msgRelatorio`, mas preciso abri-la em uma nova página.

Comment: Se quer mudar de página, por quê fazer uma requisição assíncrona e não sincrona?

Comment: Salve os dados em `LocalStorage` e depois busque-os em outra página via javascript. Se esta for uma opção válida posso postar uma resposta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conforme comentário feito por Anderson Carlos Woss. O correto a se fazer é uma requisição assíncrona. Mas enfim, você pode fazer isso usando o `LocalStorage`:

```
success: function (response) {
    localStorage.setItem('nome_salvo', JSON.stringify(response));
    // JSON.stringify para transformar os dados em formato JSON
}
```

E na outra página basta pegar os dados:

```
var consulta = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('nome_salvo'));
//JSON.parse transforma dos dados em JSON para Objetos
// Dessa forma você pode acessar os dados assim: consulta.nome
```

Depois de coletar os dados, exclua-os:

```
localStorage.removeItem('nome_salvo');
```

Comment: Olá Djalma Manfrin, sim entendi o que foi comentado, somente depois com mais calma resolvi como indicado, mas agradeço a ajuda, esse código me ajudou em uma outra questão.